# App hangs on GMSMapView allocation

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a View Controller that is embedded inside a UINavigationController that is embedded inside a UITabBarController:

```
self.find = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[Find alloc] init]];
NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tabViewControllers addObject:self.find];
[self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];
```

In that View Controller, I am trying to allocate a GMSMapView instance.

```
self.mapView = [[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

I am on version 1.9.1 of the iOS Google Maps SDK (latest version). Everything was working well in iOS7, but now that I've upgraded to iOS8, when the debugger reaches the line above - it never returns and the app hangs.

Comment: I actually moved the allocation to the app delegate and it is hanging there as well. Perhaps this is due to the fact that I am running a jail broken device on iOS8?

Answer (score 2):

Try using -
[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:camera:]

method instead. It may work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - that's what I had to begin with - didn't work. I think it has to do with the fact that I'm a Jailbroken device that was upgraded to IOS 8

Comment: ohk, not sure about that though!